# Pass Parameter to thread problem

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parameter-passing

In a datagridview I have an IP address field.
when I click on check status button I make thread for each row in datagridview and then call a remote object on the host on that IP and get some information and set another datagridview field as that info.

but there is a problem. the info is wrongly set on datagridview. why?

```
    private void button_CheckStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            IPAddress IP;
            if (IsValidIP(dataGridView["IP", i].Value.ToString(), out IP))
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(() => CheckStatusThreadFunction(IP, i));
                t.Start();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: How is it wrongly set? What results do you expect and how do the actual results differ from the expected results?

Comment: the text from get info should set in front of row i but sometimes it is set on the next or the second row below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure not to capture the loop variable:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView_VSD.Rows.Count; i++) 
    { 
        int ii = i;
        IPAddress IP; 
        if (IsValidIP(dataGridView_VSD["VSD_IP", i].Value.ToString(), out IP)) 
        { 
            Thread t = new Thread(() => CheckVSDStatusThreadFunction(IP, ii)); 
            t.Start(); 
        } 
    }
```

This is a very common mistake.

See e.g. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/InsideAnonymousMethods.aspx#6)

Comment: @HPT: added a link to my answer.

Comment: @HPT, see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for an explanation. All your anonymous delegates are capturing the same variable `i`, so it has the same value for all of them.